# ng-repeat and array doesn't repeat all array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

So i have a simple angular block like so

```
    <script>

        function smallToDo($scope){

            $scope.addToDo = function(){

                $scope.jows.push($scope.newToDo);

            }

            $scope.jows = ["kevin", "lise"];


        }

    </script>    

    <div ng-controller="smallToDo">

        <h3>To Do items:</h3>

        <input type="text" ng-model="newToDo"> <button ng-click="addToDo()">Add to do</button>

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="jow in jows"><a href="">{{jow}}</a></li>
        </ul>

        {{jows}}

    </div>
```

The problem:

- Only 1 item is added to the li repeater when you click the button
- But if you check the contents of the array with {{jows}} all values are there

Why is that?

Comment: Ok, that's strange... it's working if i create a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MEXqS/

Comment: Could you make a fiddle with your entire code ? The problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: what is the issue exactly ? The code should add one item, it adds one item, everything seems normal here

Comment: @DotDotDot: what i understood is that it is only working once.

Comment: The problem is that it adds only 1 <li>, even if i click multiple times on the button.

Comment: @Scalpweb In that case, I totally agree, the problem is somewhere else in the code

Comment: fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/MEXqS/1/ ... this shows all my code i'm working on. The code with the repeater is at the bottom. Again, it works in fiddle, but not on my local computer.

Comment: Do you have any error in your javascript console ?

Comment: @kevinius it works well in your fiddle, the item is added on click, and multiple clicks are adding the item again and again, I still don't get the problem

Comment: Yes, this is the error: 
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=jow%20in%20jows&p1=string%3Asdf

Comment: Then you can try what is explained in the page you linked, `track by $index`

Comment: But why is it working ok in the fiddle?

Comment: by the way, the error you're getting is only displayed using angular 1.2, and you set your fiddle with angular 1.1, so the fiddle works but your code doesn't

Comment: Why the votes to close and the downvotes?

Comment: So the reason it works in the fiddle is because they use angular 1.1 and i'm using 1.2. So what change have they (google) been making then that corresponds to this particular problem.

Comment: They started it in 1.1.4, it's explained in their changelog here :https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#114-quantum-manipulation-2013-04-03 , the commit is here :https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/61f2767ce65562257599649d9eaf9da08f321655

Comment: Great thx for the help, i accepted the answer, should help other people learning angular...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error occurs if there are duplicate keys in an `ngRepeat` expression. Duplicate keys are banned because AngularJS uses keys to associate DOM nodes with items.

By default, collections are keyed by reference which is desirable for most common models but can be problematic for primitive types that are interned (share references).

To resolve this error either ensure that the items in the collection have unique identity of use the track by syntax to specify how to track the association between models and DOM.

To resolve the example above can be resolved by using `track by $index`, which will cause the items to be keyed by their position in the array instead of their value.

```
<script>

    function smallToDo($scope){

        $scope.addToDo = function(){

            $scope.jows.push($scope.newToDo);

        }

        $scope.jows = ["kevin", "lise"];


    }

</script>    

<div ng-controller="smallToDo">

    <h3>To Do items:</h3>

    <input type="text" ng-model="newToDo"> <button ng-click="addToDo()">Add to do</button>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="jow in jows track by $index"><a href="">{{jow}}</a></li>
    </ul>

    {{jows}}

</div>
```